# Facebook api search in Asp.mvc 3 app

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

**EDITED**
I'm searching users in facebook using graph api in my asp.net mvc 3 application.

```
public void AsyncSearch(ICollection<JSonObject> result, string query, string objectType)
    {
        var fbClient = new FacebookClient(FacebookTokens.AccessToken);
        var searchUri = string.Format("/search?q={0}&type={1}, query, objectType);


        var tempResult = (JsonObject)fbClient.Get(searchUri);
        var elements = (JsonArray)tempResult.Values.ToArray()[0];

        elements.ForEach(element =>
                            {
                            result.Add(element);
                            });

        var next = (JsonObject)tempResult.Values.ToList()[1];

        while (next.Keys.Contains("next"))
        {
        tempResult = (JsonObject)fbClient.Get((string)next["next"]);
            elements = (JsonArray)tempResult.Values.ToArray()[0];
            elements.ForEach(element =>
                                {
                            result.Add(element);
                                });

            next = (JsonObject)tempResult.Values.ToList()[1];
        }
    }
```

But result contains at most 600 objects(each search returns different number of objects).
I think, if i put, for example, "anna" in query parameter - result must be over 10000.
Why is that? Is there any way to retrieve all users by some keyword?

Comment: The count of users who have 'USERNAME' in their name can easily change over time. What do you mean by 'all users'?

Comment: If i set USERNAME, for example, "anna" - in result at about 400 objects.I think, there are much more users with name "anna".

Comment: but you get also:  "paging": {    "next":  ... and you may get more results. You may change your request to: "/search?q=USERNAME&type=user&limit=200 -> and choose your own amount..

Comment: i set limit to 1000, but still retrieve maximum 600 objects.And i also chek paging.But i cant get all users "anna".

Answer (score 1):

For performance concerns Facebook will paginate their results.  If you look at the end of the JSON object, there should be a pageing object that has next and previous links in it.  So, to get all results you will need to run multiple queries and aggregate them up on your side.